# Is there any way of loading local resource files in dart? (not flutter)

Tags: dart, testing

I want to load the bytes of a file into a variable while testing my flutter application.
I can't use the assets directory as those are bundled with the app and require `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();`

I tried searching the file manually with the path package, but this did not seem to work and was rather hacky. That is why i'm searching for a more official approach.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is actually a duplicate of the linked question. "Bytes of a file" != asset. In any case, it is quite normal and not hacky to load files for use in tests. I keep them in a directory called `fixtures` under the `test` directory. In the test simply load it like any other file, from the path `test/fixtures/...`, i.e., `await File('test/fixtures/foo.bar').readAsBytes()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking way to complicated ...
As Chuck Batson commented, you can just use the path from the projects root for passing it into the (dart:io) File:

```
File loadResource(String relativePath) {
  final filePath = path.join("test", "resources", relativePath);
  return File(filePath);
}
```

(Notice: The above code makes use of the [path package](https://pub.dev/packages/path) for constructing a file path.)